# Function call in construcor of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm taking a Data Structures course. I'm looking at some code of a 
Linked list and there is a line of it I don't understand. Can someone please 
tell me? What is the function call in the constructor? Why isn't the new key word used?

This is the code:

```
// CONSTRUCTOR
node(
    const value_type& init_data = value_type( ),
    node* init_link = NULL
)
{ data_field = init_data; link_field = init_link; }
```

Answer (score 2):

When a function is declared, you can provide default values for parameters. This will allow the caller to provide only some of the arguments to the function, and the rest will take on these default values.

In this case, if the caller only provided one argument to the constructor (the `init_data`) the `init_link` would be `NULL`. If they provided no arguments, `init_data` would be `value_type( )` and `init_link` would be `NULL`.